# Why does Spring not inject @PersistenceContext entityManager when running on Tomcat vs standalone

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jpa, spring-annotations

I am trying to use Spring to inject `@PersistenceContext entityManager` into my service. The following configuration works standalone but does not work when deploying on Tomcat. When deploying on Tomcat, the entityManager remains null. My JPA configs are in persistence.xml.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod">
        <value>javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>persistenceUnit</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

What config changes do I need to make for injection to work on Tomcat 6 vs standalone?

Edit: I am able to get the factory inside the service and get an entityManager from it, so persistence.xml settings seem to be working correctly.

**Solution:**
I enabled Spring logging to find the issue -- a missing library. Apparently Spring fails quietly if the above `transactionManager` bean cannot be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you must make sure that persistence.xml exist in proper path on your tomact, or more accurate - in your classpath. 
At least I had issues like that when working on enterprise application , so I guess this is a good place to start looking for an answer. 
 
Did you check the logs? Do they have anything interesting about this?